# SQLError : Table does not exist

Tags: java, sql, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have created a basic SpringBoot application to create a table in SQL database

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserServiceApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

   @Autowired
   JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(UserServiceApplication.class, args);
   }

   @Override
   public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      String sql = "INSERT INTO micro_users (fullname, email, password) values (?, ? ,?)";
      int result = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, "MyName", "hell@gmail.com",  "2021");
      System.out.println("result " + result);
   }
}
```

This is what I have in my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/microservices
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

This is what I have added in application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/microservices
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  application:
    name: service
  main:
      allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
      lazy-initialization: true


  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto:update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

**I am not able to access my database. What can I be doing incorrectly.**

I did create a local database with the below connection details :

```
Name: Local instance
Host: localhost
Port: 3306
Login user: root
Current user: root@localhost
Version: 8.0.33
```

The error I receive is :

```
T10:37:09.815-05:00  INFO 12812 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-07-05T10:37:10.102-05:00  INFO 12812 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-05T10:37:10.115-05:00  WARN 12812 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-07-05T10:37:10.130-05:00  INFO 12812 --- [           main] c.b.user.service.UserServiceApplication  : Started UserServiceApplication in 3.897 seconds (process running for 4.33)
2023-07-05T10:37:10.182-05:00  INFO 12812 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'microservices.micro_users' doesn't exist
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
```

Comment: Is there perhaps something in the start log?

Comment: @Twistleton updated the question with the details. Thanks

Comment: You just need to add one space between `ddl-auto:update`. And try to rerun your code after changing `ddl-auto: create` after successfull run, you  have to set again `ddl-auto: update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a space to ddl-auto: update worked. I also noticed that the ddl-auto command text changed to yellow after the change like others, so something to look for when we write commands in yml file.